# $ionicLoading Not Displaying When Adding To Function Call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a logout function that is invoked when the logout link is clicked. I'm wanting to using the $ionicLoading animation to indicate that there is a process taking place during logout as I'm clearing data and reloading a route. I'm using this on the login function and it works perfectly, but on the logout function it does not load the animation.

I debug using chrome and I can't see any glaring reason why it's not loading the animation. I am loading the $ionicLoading dependency in the controller.

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
$scope.logout = function() {

   $ionicLoading.show({
     content: 'Loading',
     animation: 'fade-in',
     showBackdrop: true,
     maxWidth: 200,
     showDelay: 20
    });


  var logoutFunc = function() {
  userService.RemoveUser();
  $rootScope.userLoggedIn = false;
  $scope.user = null;
  $location.path('app/home');
  $window.location.reload();
  $ionicLoading.hide();
  }

  logoutFunc();

};
```

Comment: What if `showDelay: 0`

Comment: Same behavior. It was 0 and I was trying that to see if that would result in it loading. No luck

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. The $window.location.reload() was killing the $ionicLoading.show(). I removed the $ionicLoading.hide() and added it to a $timeout function and works perfectly.